# Erro ao alterar altura de um elemento

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `iframe` com um vídeo do youtube dentro dele.

Quero que ele fique com a lergura de 100% da página, isso está ok, mas quero que a altura fique proporcional à largura.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <iframe id="video" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:0px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zVWJR4K5Vt4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    //pego a largura
    largura = screen.width;
    //utilizo uma regra de três pra calcular a altura
    altura = largura * 315 / 560;
    //aqui é onde eu tento alterar a altura via código, mas não está funcionando
    Document.getElementById('video').css('height', altura);
</script>
```

Comment: Não existe **Document** o correto é **document**.

Comment: Tbm não é assim que se muda o css através de **Javascript**, é assim: `document.getElementById('video').style.height = altura;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem problemas no código:

O correto é `document` (tudo minúsculo).

Valores do CSS precisam de uma unidade (`px`, `em`, `%` etc...).

O método `.css()` é um método jQuery, e você está selecionando o elemento como um objeto JavaScript: `document.getElementById('video')`.

Se estiver usando jQuery, o correto seria:

```
$("#video").css("height", altura+"px");
```

Com JavaScript puro seria:

```
document.getElementById('video').style.height = altura+"px";
```